# mssql_fetch_array not returning false?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got a php script that is supposed to generate images based on an MS SQL database (specifically, greetings cards for our first-year students). For some reason, after it runs out of rows in the result resource, mssql_fetch_array() goes back to the start of the result rather than returning false. Can anyone tell me why this could be?

The actual messages are in .txt files on the server, due to MS SQL Server's habit of mangling the punctuation. Database fields are `id | fname | sname | tutgrp | house`.

Relevant portion of code:

```
    $dbConn = mssql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die("Connection to database failed");
mssql_select_db($dbData, $dbConn) or die("Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM newIntakeTest;";
$result = mssql_query($query, $dbConn) or die("Unable to query");

while(False !== ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)))
{
    array_walk($row, 'trim_value');
    echo $row["sname"].", ".$row["fname"]."... ";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng("res/".$row["house"].".png");
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
    //tutor msg
    imagettftext($image, 35, 0, 57, 86, $black, $fontBold, "Message from your Tutor:");
    $fn = "in/".$row["tutgrp"].".txt";
    $fh = fopen($fn,'r');
    $tutormsg = fread($fh,filesize($fn));
    fclose($fh);
    imagettftext($image, 35, 0, 57, 139, $black, $fontStd, wrap(35,0,$fontStd,$tutormsg,1640));

    //HoH msg
    imagettftext($image, 35, 0, 57, 1399, $black, $fontBold, "A message from ".$heads[$row["house"]].", Head of ".$row["house"]." house:");
    $fn = "in/".$row["house"].".txt";
    $fh = fopen($fn,'r');
    $headmsg = fread($fh,filesize($fn));
    fclose($fh);
    imagettftext($image, 35, 0, 57, 1455, $black, $fontStd, wrap(35,0,$fontStd,$headmsg,1640));

    printaligned($image, "To: ".$row["fname"]." ".$row["sname"], $fontStd, 70, 450, $black);
    printaligned($image, "From: ".substr($row["house"],0,1)."-".$row["tutgrp"], $fontStd, 70, 1985, $black);
    printaligned($image, $row["house"]." House", $fontStd, 70, 2130, $black);

    imagepng($image,"out/".$row["id"]."_".$row["sname"]."_".$row["fname"].".png");
    echo "done.<br />";
    imagedestroy($image);

}
```

Comment: Seems what the manual says. Bu the `False !==` is redundant. PHP is capable of evaluating arrays in boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while to:

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

You are using False, not false - that will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the typical convention is just

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
```